# How to display Json data from a method inside a livewire component into a view?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component method that's update a value each time a user choses a select option.

```
public function updatedWil()
    {
        $this->fees = DB::table('delivery_fees')
            ->select('stopdesk', 'domicile')
            ->where('destination', $this->wil)
            ->get()->toJson();
            //dd($this->fees);
        $result = response()->json($this->fees);
        return view('livewire.form-elements',compact('result'));
    }
```

this method above returns a two values `domicile` and `stopdesk` based on a destination selected by a user.

```
"[
 {"stopdesk":615,
  "domicile":1040
 }
]
"
```

**What am trying to do here is to send this values to my view:`'livewire.form-elements'` and display it on a `foreach.`and display it on an radio type input. **

```
<div class="flex items-center mb-4">
 <input checked id="default-radio-1" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="415" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label for="default-radio-1" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                à domicile: 415DA</label>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
            <input id="default-radio-2" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="315" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label for="default-radio-2" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                StopDesk:  315 DA</label>
        </div>
```

I tried to return it with `compact` method like this:

```
 $result = response()->json($this->fees);
 return view('livewire.form-elements',compact('result'));
```

and used a `foreach` loop with `json_decode` and display it in my view like this:

```
        @foreach (json_decode($result,true) as $items)
        <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
            <input checked id="default-radio-1" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="415" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label for="default-radio-1" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                à domicile: {{ $items->domicile }} DA</label>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
            <input id="default-radio-2" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="315" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label for="default-radio-2" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                StopDesk: {{ $items->domicile }} DA</label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

**Unfortunately it throws back an error of `Undefined variable $result on view`.**

Comment: What's the reason for using json here?

Comment: because if I try to use only ->get() It throws an error  "must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]"

Comment: Where does it throw that error? Isn't it common in Laravel/Livewire to `->get()` your results and pass them to the view? You probably did something wrong then.

Comment: Why use a `response()`? Why use `response()->json()` on an already JSON'ified result? Why use object notation when you set `json_decode`'s second parameter to `true`, which will return JSON objects as associative arrays?

Comment: I am a bit new to this if you could tell me how to do it right and display those values on my blade I will appreciate it.

Comment: I'd suggest you get rid of all the JSON stuff and get and pass data the "usual" Laravel way. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#passing-data-to-views If any error pops up feel free to ask a new question. Good luck

Comment: it didn't work the usual way!! can you write me a close code of how I do it.

Comment: "_it didn't work_" Doesn't help anyone, blank page? If you encounter errors it is best to post the _complete_ error message. It would also help if you posted the code you have that failed, as I said, feel free to ask a new question (including your new code and errors you encounter). I won't write your code, there's documentation available that explains every step needed. Good luck

Comment: alright thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following error:

```
"must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]"
```

Happens whenever you try to cast an unrecognized object to a public variable in livewire. There are two ways to work around this:

**Use a model instead of the DB helper**

So you can write your query like this:

```
$this->yourPublicVariable = DeliveryFees::select('stopdesk', 'domicile')
        ->where('destination', $this->wil)
        ->get()
```

By using a model, Livewire does know you are passing a collection, which will prevent the type error.

**Pass the variable along side the view**

```
        $json = DB::table('delivery_fees')
        ->select('stopdesk', 'domicile')
        ->where('destination', $this->wil)
        ->get()->toJson();

    return view('livewire.form-elements',['json' => $json]);
```

This way the variable is passed once, instead of having been attached to the component, downside of doing it this way is that on the next update the passed variable won't be available anymore.